# How do I fit a Generalised Linear Mixed Model to 3D coordinate data, where the outcome is binary?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, spatial, glmm

I'm trying to understand how I might fit a Generalised Linear Mixed Model (GLMM) to a data set comprising 3D coordinates, with a binary outcome. The basic set-up is as follows:

1. Each subject has its own id, subj_id.
2. Each subject has its own volume, subj_vol.
3. Each subject possesses one or more spots, where each spot is described by its volume, spot_vol, and its centroid, (x, y, z).
4. The coordinates of each spot's centroid are measured relative to the associated subject's origin, where each axis varies from 0 to 1. In this sense, centroid coordinates only describe the location of a spot on a particular subject.
5. Each spot belongs to one of two possible categories, so our outcome variable is spot_type.

The question I want to answer is: does spot_type depend on one (or more) of the x, y and z components?

My first attempt at solving this problem was to fit a Generalised Linear Mixed Model (mixed, because one subject can contain multiple spots), with subj_id modelled as a random effect. In R, I used the glmer function in the lme4 library:

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- glmer(spot_type ~ x + y + z + subj_vol + spot_vol + (1 | subj_id), data = xyz_dat, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(m1)
```

This seemed reasonable enough (I think!). However, I'm now concerned that I should have included a three-way interaction between the x, y and z coordinates (which, if my understanding is correct, would account for the possibility that spot_type could vary "off-axis" -- for example, from one corner to another, rather than just varying along each axis):

```
m2 <- glmer(spot_type ~ x * y * z + subj_vol + spot_vol + (1 | subj_id), data = xyz_dat, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(m2)
```

The problem is that, by including multiple interactions in the model (as per m2), the main effects for x, y and z are no longer interpretable in the usual way. Moreover, for my data set, I find that m1 produces no significant coefficients, whilst m2 produces a significant y coefficient (p=0.00839) with no significant interaction terms (which seems counter-intuitive).

Does anybody have any experience fitting a GLMM to coordinate data? If so, is it correct to include interactions involving components (as in m2)? Or am I simply barking up the wrong tree with GLMMs (i.e. is there a more appropriate way to answer my question)?